# Expected value of truncated distribution

Tags: integration, probability-distributions, random-variables, expected-value

This definition is taken from the [Wikipedia page for truncated distribution:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_distribution)

Let $X$ be a random variable with a continuous distribution, $f(x)$ be its probability density function and $F(x)$ be its cumulative distribution function.

Now the truncated distribution where the top of the distribution has been removed is as follows:
$$f(x|X\le y)=\frac{g(x)}{F(y)}$$
where $g(x)=f(x)$ for all $x\le y$ and $g(x)=0$ everywhere else.

I am trying to derive the expected value of the $f(x|X\le y)$ and I am thinking about using the conditional expectation the following way for the case when $x\le y$.
$$E(X|X\le y)=\int^y_{-\infty} x_{X|X\le Y}f(x|x\le y)dx=\int^y_{-\infty}x\frac{f(x)}{F(y)}dx$$
but I don't know how to continue from here since I am not sure what happens to $F(y)$.

Comment: you can just factor out $F(y)$ to get $\frac{1}{F(y)}\int_{-\infty}^y x f(x) dx$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notice that $y$ is a constant, hence $F(y)$ is a constant.

That is

$$E(X|X \le y) = \frac{\int_{-\infty}^y xf(x) \, dx}{F(y)}$$

This is consistent with the formula given on the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_distribution)

$$\frac{\int_a^b xf(x) \, dx}{F(b)-F(a)}$$ since we have

$$\lim_{t\to -\infty}F(t)=0$$